# Alexa app: How to choose the device to drop in on

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

I have multiple Alexa Dots on my account and when using the app on my Android phone I do not get the option to choose which device to drop in on. It constantly defaults to one device. When I try a verbal command with the device name it tells me it cannot be found even though I see in on my account as online.

Answer (score 3):

Name each Dot something unique (in the Alexa app, Devices-> Echo & Alexa-> select a device-> Edit Name). Then say, “Alexa drop in on (device name).”